# Doubt about two different ways of taking the supremum of a sequence of functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, supremum-and-infimum

As per my understanding:

Functions:

$\sup_{x \in I} f(x) = \sup  \{y \in \mathbb{R}: y = f(x), x \in I\}.$

*Example:*  $f(x) = x^2$ and $I = [0,3)$:
$\sup_{x \in I} f(x) = 9$.

Sequence of functions:

$g(x)=\sup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f_n(x) = \sup \{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y = f_{n}(x), n \in \mathbb{N}\}  \tag{1},$ where $x$ is *fixed*.

*Example:* $f_n(x) = x^n$

1. $\forall x> 0, x \neq 1, g(x)=\sup\{x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,......\}= +\infty$.
2. $x=1: g(x)=\sup\{1,1,1,1,....\}=1$
3. $x=0: g(x)=\sup\{0,0,0,0,....\}=0.$
4. $x = -1$: $g(x)=\sup\{-1,1,-1,1,....\}=1$
5. $\forall x<0, x \neq -1$: $g(x)=\sup\{x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,.....\}=+\infty$.

But there is also another way of taking the supremum of a sequence of functions:

> $\sup_{x \in I} f_n(x) = \sup \{y \in \mathbb{R}: y = f_n(x) , x \in I\}=(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}  \tag{2}$

*Example:* $I =[0,3)$: $
(g_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} =\sup_{x \in I=[0,3)}f_n(x)=3^n.$

*My conclusion*:  $(1)$ and $(2)$ are two different ways of taking $\sup f_n(x)$ and are used according to the specific needs.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct. Was there a question?

Comment: @KurtG. I wasn't sure of the correctness of my line of reasoning. I thought there was some counterexample of some sort.

Comment: If it helps: one always takes supremum of a *set*. There are many different sets one can make, given a sequence of functions. You've described two common families of sets that are made.